# seaborn AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'set'

Tags: python, seaborn

I have anaconda2 in my windows10, and install seaborn by the command:

```
conda install seaborn
```

Then I download an example from seaborn website:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.set(style="ticks")

# Load the example dataset for Anscombe's quartet
df = sns.load_dataset("anscombe")

# Show the results of a linear regression within each dataset
sns.lmplot(x="x", y="y", col="dataset", hue="dataset", data=df,
       col_wrap=2, ci=None, palette="muted", size=4,
       scatter_kws={"s": 50, "alpha": 1})
```

After I run the example in my command prompt, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "seaborn.py", line 1, in <module>
    import seaborn as sns
  File "E:\OneDrive\seek_backward\caiwufenxi\source\seaborn.py", line 5, in   <module>
  df = sns.load_dataset("anscombe")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_dataset'
```

Has anyone encounterd the same problem? How can I solve it? Thanks!

Comment: you apparently named one of your scripts `seaborn.py`. This shadows the module import. Rename it, and it will probably work.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I rename the scripts and that error is removed, but it reports a new error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_dataset'`. What's the cause?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the stacktrace it seems like your script is named `seaborn.py` (`File "seaborn.py", line 1, in <module>`... `File "E:\OneDrive\seek_backward\caiwufenxi\source\seaborn.py", line 5, in   <module>`). Try to rename it in something else (like `test1.py`) and retry.

You are actually trying to import your local seaborn script (which doesn't have a load_dataset function) and not the installed module.

Answer (score 2):

Just rename your script name from "seaborn.py" to something else.